# update the only text field data into the database in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a updateProf Jframe form in my application, where the user can update his or her profile information. What my problem is that when the user clicks update button, it also updates the records which are not changed in the text fields. here is my code,

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String value1 = changePass.getText();
        String value2 = changeFN.getText();
        String value3 = changeLN.getText();
        String value4 = jTextField1.getText();
        String value5 = gender;
        String value6 = changeEmail.getText();
        String value7 = changePhone.getText();
        String value8 = changePost.getText();
        //byte[] value9 = person_image;

        String sql = "update registration set password = '"+value1+"', firstName='"+value2+"', lastName='"+value3+"',date='"+value4+"', "
                + "gender= '"+value5+"', Email = '"+value6+"', ph_number = '"+value7+"', zipCode = '"+value8+"'  where username = '"+name+"'";
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         pst.execute();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);


    }
```

what i want is that only the text field which is updated, should be updated in the database. Please do help me.

Comment: Start by having a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: *"what i want is that only the text field which is updated, should be updated in the database. Please do help me."* - Why?  Is there a efficiency reason for it?  Maintaining information about which fields have changed and then generating a dynamic query would complicated

Comment: yes..thanks..i was thinking the same. well there would be a question for efficiency but the app i am making is not on a bigger scale, so efficiency is out of question. it was just for my own knowledge. thanks